# winforms - write to RichTextBox in a form without showing the form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application for a end-user (not me).
For troubleshooting situations, I want to have a seperate form with a text box (RichTextBox) that acts as a online log, this way if I am running the program at the end-user station, I can see that everything is working/ something is wrong.

I also want the end-user to be able to call me mid-run and I can open the online log and see what happend until now (not just open a log file and see everythis until now, but see everything until now and continue working with the application and the online log).
I dont want the end-user to see the online log, I created a button on the main form that shows the online log on demand.

I created a second form that acts as a log, but if i am writing to the text box in the log form without showing the log form first, it does not seems to work (when I use LogForm.Show() from the button in the main form, the log form text box is empty).
I have to first use
LogForm.Show()
than i can hide the log form (using LogForm.Hide()), and next time I am showing the log form (using LogForm.Show()), I do see everything until now in the log form.

I am searching for a solution for this problem, now i am just using
LogForm.Show();
LogForm.Hide();
in the main form init but as a result the log form is flickering once and the end-user sometimed confuse by that.

Sorry for the lack of code, the progrem is created in a stand-alone network (no internet).

Thank you.

Comment: You need to flush() the write data.  Windows uses timers (as well as temp buffer size) to move data to/from streams.  So the end of the data may not still be in a stream.

Comment: init log form, make some method for loggining as public. And when you will click show before created form.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*it does not seems to work* - couldn't reproduce this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form f2 = new Form();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        f2.Controls.Add(new RichTextBox() { Name = "rtb1" });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (f2.Controls["rtb1"] as RichTextBox).AppendText(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}
```

I created a form with two buttons, wired their click event handlers up as shown. Thi form has another form as a class wide variable, onto which a richtextbox is placed. One of the buttons adds log entries to the rich textbox, the other button shows the log form (f2)

Clicking one button (the log-a-message button) several times, then the other button (the show-the-log-form button) causes the logging form to appear with all the text entered into the textbox just fine. Clicking the log-a-message button some more causes further text to be entered into the logging form :

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right, this is why I added a comment that problem solved.
It's probably something else that I messed up in the beginning.
Thank you for your answer.